# Database design (SQL CE) in Mvc 4 project using Entity Framework Code First - a few questions

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design

In the application I'm developing a user is presented with a number of preferences that they should personalise. The following describes how I think it should be implemented:

A preference:

```
public enum Weighting { One, Two, Three, Four, Five, 
                        Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten }

public class PreferenceOption
{
    public bool PreferenceOptionSelected { get; set; }
    public Weighting Weighting { get; set; }
}
```

PreferenceOptionSelected will more than likely be a bool; if selected the user can add a weighting, if not selected no weighting can be applied, but the application still needs to know that its value is false - this is to facilitate searching later on.

A class to hold all available preferences:

```
public class PreferenceOptions
{
    public PreferenceOption WantsHouse = new PreferenceOption()
    { PreferenceOptionSelected = false, Weighting = Weighting.One };
    // ... could be up to 15/20 options   
}
```

A class to hold a user's selected/personal preferences:

```
public class UserPreferences
{
    public List<PreferenceOptions> UserPreferences { get; set; }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is this design the best way to approach this kind of scenario?
2. I'm using EF Code First. Do these 3 class need to persist as entities in the database? Or, could `PreferenceOption` and `PreferenceOptions` exist only in-memory and be used to facilitate attaining a final 'list' of `UserPreferences`. This is the part I can't get my head around. How would I best store a user's preferences? What would the table make-up be?
3. A list was my first thought on how to store a user's preferences, but I know that an outright list cannot be stored in a row, but it can if serialised to XML. A user's preferences will be important later on to facilitate searching, if I used the XML approach would deserialising before searching be inefficient/cause a performance overhead. Is there a better approach to the one I'm thinking?

Comment: Are the preferences application layer oriented or data layer oriented? That is, do you expect to use the weighting value as a part of some query in the database, or is it simply something that you would use in the application code to shuffle around the results that have been returned? Also, does every user have the same number of preferences, or is it flexible per user?

Comment: Are the `WantsHouse` things fixed in number and meaning or will that part be dynamic?

Comment: Yes, a weighting would be used as part of some query in the database e.g. if a weighting was 1 for a particular option, some records in the database might be ignored, if it was 10, some records would definitely be returned - if that makes sense? Ever user will be presented with the same number of options, all will be required - but if a user doesn't choose to use the option it's value of false should still be recorded, as this could/will impact search results.

Comment: @SWeko, instances of PreferenceOption will more than likely be fixed in number, but there is a chance in the future that another option could be added. Their meaning will always be representative of what the instance name is i.e. WantsHouse. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Any further questions? Maybe an opinion/answer?