# Entity Framework Code First, 1:1 association with inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, associations

I have an abstract class `UserProfile`, it has a subclass `Tenant`, so the relationship is 1:1 - one 'user' is one 'tenant'.

Is this the correct way to implement table-per-type inheritance, on a 1:1 basis?

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public abstract class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    // ...
}

[Table("Tenant")]
public class Tenant : UserProfile
{
    public string PersonalDescription { get; set; }
    // ...

    // Navigation property on dependant end
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

- Am I correct in placing the navigation property on the dependant end of the relationship? Or does it matter what end it goes on?
- Would I need to also place a navigation property of type `Tenant` in
  `UserProfile`?
- Finally, I read that it is worthwhile making every property in a model `virtual` to help EF with change tracking - is this necessary?

Comment: If it is a table-per-type scenario, you do not need navigation properties. Tenant does not contain a UserProfile, Tenant is a UserProfile.

Comment: Okay, but how does EF know it's a table-per-type situation? Am I explicitly enforcing it by placing the table annotation on derived classes?

Comment: Well, yes. EF should be able to get the values of the `Tenant` fields from the `Tenant` table, and the fields inherited from `UserProfile` from the `UserProfile` table. Looks magical, but it works, at least for me :)

Comment: Thanks. One other thing, in this ( http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx ) tutorial, in the DbContext class, only one DbSet is used - that of the base class. Is this all that is needed to create tables for the subclasses? Or do I need to create DbSets for each derived class too?

Comment: Added an answer from the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a table-per-type scenario you do not need navigation properties. Tenant does not contain a UserProfile, Tenant is a UserProfile.

EF should be able to get the values of the Tenant fields from the Tenant table, and the fields inherited from UserProfile from the UserProfile table. Looks magical, but it works, at least for me :)

As for the DbSets, if you need to directly use a `Tenant` collection, you could add a `Tenants` DbSet. That would enable you to do:

```
myContext.Tenants.Where(t => ... t.PersonalDescription ... t.UserId ...)
```

which is equivalent with the longer and less discoverable

```
myContext.UserProfiles.OfType<Tenant>.Where(t => ....)
```

My personal preference is not to use the declared DbSets at all, and use the `Set<T>()` method directly in a wrapping repository, that exposes methods like `GetByKey`, `Update` etc.., but that is a matter of taste.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm not sure if this is allowed, but I'm kind of desperate for an answer/opinion. If you'd care to look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14477961/database-design-sql-ce-in-mvc-4-project-using-entity-framework-code-first-a I'd really appreciate it.